# Compilation influence on mobile apps?

Tags: android, c++, ios

So when you create mobile apps, you usually intend to distribute your app to multiple platforms and architectures. However, since object code usually is dependent on factors like the architecture, you would have to compile the app for all the different mobile phones out there. So is you application really compiled for all the different phones that the app will be made available for? Is this specifically targeted compilation then done whenever a user runs the app on his/her device? Like on the device itself or is the compilation done before the app is actually installed on the phone?

Comment: "_you would have to compile the app for all the different mobile phones out there._" That is like saying "To release a desktop application, you need to compile it for all the different computers out there", which is, frankly, not true. Typically, compilation for all relevant OS's, are enough.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah, I also thought that it sounded a little extreme. But if the compilation is targeted for the general OS, then architecture-dependent optimizations aren't really doable, right?

Comment: And does your comment also imply that the compilation is done before the app is installed on a user device?

Comment: Look over the analogy, that I have given you, one more time, and explain, why do you think mobile apps is different from desktop apps, regarding compilation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Related:  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/arch   You need to compile windows apps multiple times too if you plan to run it on multiple architectures.   Android studio just makes it easy because it's already cross compiling for most NDKs

Comment: @UKMonkey But so whether it is IOS, Android or Windows, compilation is not being done on the user devices and thus compilation time will not have any effect on the user experience, right?

Comment: @UKMonkey Sure.. I still fail to see how it's mobile apps specific. Since, the same issues exist in desktop applications.

Comment: @asd compilation is done when you create the package; with the shared objects being shipped as part of the package.  The user will be unaware of their existence

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius:  Remember that different platforms can be run with different processors.  A desktop PC with an ARM processor running windows will not accept code compiled for an Intel processor, even though they both run windows Os.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sure, I remembered that after my initial comment, that most compilers that I have seen, have an option, to specify the destination architecture. I still fail to see how mobile apps are special in this regard. That's why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is you application really compiled for all the different phones
>   that the app will be made available for?

Short answer: yes.

> Is this specifically targeted compilation then done whenever a user
>   runs the app on his/her device?

No; this is done when the package is created (else you'd be sending all your source code in the app!)  This means a package may contain multiple libraries required for it to run on multiple architectures.

> Like on the device itself or is the compilation done before the app is actually installed on the phone?

For the shared object to be put into the package, compilation is done before the package is created.  The required shared objects are copied onto the phone during installation of the package (and I suspect that the non-required ones are discarded, but it's possible they're not!).

There are however only a relatively small number of architectures that android supports; and while supporting them all does increase the size of the package, the size is rarely an issue.

**Alternative:**

If you don't want to put the shared object in the package, an alternative is to host them and download the appropriate one during runtime.

The problem with this is that this does impact user experience (I personally hate when I download an app, and then it states that it wants to download more;  it feels like it's a mechanism of bypassing any security checks google want to do)